# There is a large gap in the background between or among students?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I want to write a sentence

> 'There is a large gap in the background between/among students'.

I am struggling to figure out the correct answer, even though I looked at similar questions. On one hand I think the answer should be among, because there are many students. But on the other hand, the way I'm thinking about this is kinda like I take two students at a time and compare and conclude there is a large gap, so maybe it should be between? I'm getting rather confused with this. Any clarification would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to say. Do you mean that students come from a wide range of different family backgrounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying there is **a** large gap, that can mean there is only one. A single gap can only be *between* two things.

If you mean to say that there is a single gap between two specific students, you could say:

> There is a large gap between (these) two students.

If you mean that there are multiple gaps between *all* the students, you could say:

> There *are* large *gaps* between the students.

"Among" doesn't sound appropriate however many gaps or students you are talking about. Something 'among' items is *surrounded* by them.